# From segues to show/present view controller

Tags: ios, swift3, segue

I've some problems in changing segues to show or present ViewController.
That code works

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let noteDetailViewController = segue.destination as! NoteViewController
    var selectedNote: Note?

    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {
        if let selectedNoteCell = sender as? NoteTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedNoteCell)!
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            if !searchIsEmpty() {
                selectedNote = filteredNotes[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                selectedNote = notes[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    } else if segue.identifier == "RemindLater" {
        if let note = notificationNote?.copy() as? Note {
            selectedNote = note
        }
    }
    noteDetailViewController.note = selectedNote?.copy() as? Note
    noteDetailViewController.oldNote = selectedNote?.copy() as? Note
    noteDetailViewController.isFiltered = isFiltered
    resultSearchController.searchBar.isHidden = true
}
```

It called by

```
vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "RemindLater", sender: self)
```

I tried to do a func with the same purpose, but for using show/present method.
It looks like this

```
func remindLater() {
    if let note = notificationNote?.copy() as? Note {
        noteToEditing = note
        noteViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        noteViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        noteViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
        noteViewController.note = noteToEditing?.copy() as? Note
        noteViewController.oldNote = noteToEditing?.copy() as? Note
        noteViewController.isFiltered = isFiltered
        resultSearchController.searchBar.isHidden = true
        present(noteViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //show(noteViewController, sender: self)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. When i setting up my objects on view controller (after calling remindLater method) in viewDidLoad method i found all objects like UIDatePicked and others equal to nil. It's not like this using segue. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell on what you are trying to do, it sounds like you need to get a reference to the controller in the prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) by instantiating it and then setting the properties directly.

I could be off base, but I'm talking something like:

```
// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if "RemindLater" == segue.identifier {

        let controller = segue.destination as! NewViewController
        controller.note = noteToEditing
        ...

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using prepare for segue method?